# sql query counting something across three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables with some columns shown below:

```
Table 1 - airports: NAME IATA, COUNTRY
Table 2 - airlines: NAME, IATA
Table 3 - routes: AIRLINE, SOURCE AIRPORT, DESTINATION AIRPORT
```

I want to write an SQLite query which finds out how many countries certain airlines fly to.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT al.NAME AS 'Airline Name',
       COUNT(r.AIRLINE) AS 'No. of Destinations'
FROM airlines as al
INNER JOIN routes r ON r.AIRLINE = al.IATA
INNER JOIN airports ap ON r.DESTINATION_AIRPORT = ap.IATA
GROUP BY ap.COUNTRY
ORDER BY [No. of Destinations] DESC;
```

I'm getting an incredibly wrong result. Help would be appreciated please and thank you. (those joins are the links between the tables for those who want to try and write a query for me)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite? (The dbms should raise an exception here...)

Comment: SQLite. Yeah im having trouble structuring the query, do you know how i could write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major problems with your query:

1. The `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY`.
2. You are not counting the countries, which seems to be what you want.

Tweaking your query fixes this problem:

```
SELECT al.NAME AS Airline_Name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cp.country) AS num_countries
FROM airlines al INNER JOIN
     routes r
     ON r.AIRLINE = al.IATA INNER JOIN 
     airports ap
     ON r.DESTINATION_AIRPORT = ap.IATA
GROUP BY al.name;
```

Note:  I strongly discourage you from using single quotes for column names.  The simplest approach is to use column names that don't require escaping.  Then only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Do you know how i could write a query to see how many different countries one airport can fly to?

Comment: That would be a different question, but the idea is the same . . . `group by` and `count(distinct)`.